# Dynamic Table with custom validation

Tags: ajax, forms, wicket

First, I show you want I want to do.

I need something like form with a lot of lists. One list is the structure row1, row2, ... with the "**+**" button.
Every item from list (row1, row2) has `setRequired(true)` but I want enable validation only after **save** click. I suppouse that icon "**+**"  is AjaxButton wich adds another row but not validate previous rows.

How to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can define whether a Button validates a form or not by using `setDefaultFormProcessing` setting it to true will have the button validate the form while setting it to false will hav the button skip validation.

See the JavaDoc for [Button](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/Button.html) for more information.